# Recursive CTE confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server

An earlier post today got me thinking about using a recursive CTE.  Basically, the goal is to have a simple table with hours and 15 minute increments, like so:

```
HOUR   MINUTE
1      15
1      30
1      45
1      60
2      15
2      30
...
```

This seemed like a fine opportunity for a recursive CTE.  However, when I try to do both parts in a CTE, it just runs forever, spitting out a infinite number of rows.

```
with 
cteMin as (
  select 15 as mnt
  union select 30
  union select 45
  union select 60),
cte
as (
select 1 as hour
  ,0 as mnt
union all
select 
hour + 1,
cteMin.mnt
from cte
cross join cteMin 
where hour < 24

)

select * from CTE
```

If I instead move the minutes part down as a derived query, it behaves fine, returning 96 rows.

```
with cte as 
( select 1 as theHour
union all
select theHour + 1
from cte
where theHour <24)

select * from cte 
cross join
(select 15 as theMin
union select 30
union select 45
union select 60) as Mins
```

Am I missing something, or doing something wrong?  Because at this point, this makes no sense to me.

Comment: Don't use a recursive CTE for this - it doesn't scale (and it may not matter at 96 rows, but why not always use something that scales, even in cases where it doesn't matter)? You want a numbers table to help facilitate queries like this - see http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1, http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2, http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Comment: The cross join is exploding - the first iteration will have 4 results, the next 4 x 4, the next 4 x 4 x 4 etc. Drop the criteria down to `< 3` or `< 4` to see what's going on